# Wrapper isn't executed in a script set to execute in Crontab

Tags: perl, ssh, cron, solaris

I have a perl script, which is set to run via crontab. This script calls a wrapper script while executing. The wrapper script's main job is to execute commands on a remote server like

```
ssh root@10.1.1.1 ls -lrt > /tmp/output.txt
```

I am calling the wrapper inside the main script as

```
system("nohup perl wrapper $date $IP 2> /dev/null &");
```

Now when all is done, the main script fetches the output.txt which were created by all the wrappers from all servers in the end with scp. Now the problem is that the commands in the wrapper are not being executed. While the main script can scp .. What can be the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Cron will not execute the wrapper because of the path. The complete path to wrapper should be mentioned.

```
system("nohup perl /export/home/myscript/wrapper $date $IP 2> /dev/null &");
```